# What is the pattern of this sequence of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$5,\,7,\,14,\,16,\,33,\,55,\,82,\,114$

I was given this sequence of numbers, but I can't find the pattern to it.
I have put them into different online sequence calculators, but they did not work.

This sequence was given to me by a math teacher friend. It was for her 8th grade students. She couldn't figure it out. The first 5 numbers were given, and the question said to find the next 3. Her answer book give the last 3. I agree that it doesn't seem right, so I wanted to ask here before I told her.

Comment: Do you have any context where the sequence comes from?

Comment: There is no answer to a question like this. At least not without a lot of context.

Comment: Are you sure there is no mistake? 5, 7, 14, 26, 43, 65, 92, 124 would make sense.

Comment: This sequence was given to me by a math teacher friend. It was for her 8th grade students. She couldn't figure it out. The first 5 numbers were given, and the question said to find the next 3. Her answer book give the last 3. I agree that it doesn't seem right, so I wanted to ask here before I told her.

Comment: At least you need to rephrase your question, so we can help you to find the right answer..

Comment: It looks like $a_{n+1}\approx a_n+a_{n-1}$.

Comment: In view of the OP's clarification 14 hours ago, putting the question on hold 11 hours ago was inexcusable.

Answer (score 2):

The last five numbers actually follow a straightforward pattern: the first differences are $17,22,27$, and $32$, increasing by $5$ each time. Project this back, and first three first differences should be (in reverse order) $12,7$, and $2$. They are in fact $2,7$, and $2$, which leads me to believe that the sequence was supposed to be

$$5,7,14,26,43,65,92,124\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

How did you get this sequence? What makes you think there has to be a pattern? The standard reference for questions like this is [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/). It can't find a match for your sequence, so you'll have to provide more information if you really want an answer.